# Как импортировать файл из папки выше в python?

Tags: python

Имеется следующая структура:

```
main - submain_1 - file1.py
     - submain_2 - file2.py
```

Как я могу в file2 импортировать класс из file1? Уже пытался так

```
from ..submain_1.file1 import class
```

но получаю ошибку: 'ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По-моему как-то так:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
from submain_1.file1 import class
```